# Searching list of words in scrabble with blank tile using Python

Tags: python

I have a scrabble challenge and have the following list of letters:

```
letters = ['t', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

And following list of words:

```
word = ['apple', 'whisky', 'yutz', 'xray', 'tux', 'zebra']
```

Here is the code I'm using to find the words which can be made for a given *list of letters*:

```
def valid_word(word, letters):
    available_letters = letters[:]

    candidate = True

    for letter in word:
        if letter not in available_letters:     
            candidate = False
        else:
            available_letters.remove(letter)
    if candidate == True:
        return candidate
```

It gives me output that two words '*yutz'* and '*tux*' can be made for the current list of letters.

My challenge is **what if we replace one of the *letter* in the *list of letters* with blank denoted as `'_'` in the list. For example `'t'` is replaced by `'_'`** below:

```
letters = ['_', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

How can code still be able to find the same words 'yutz' and 'tux' but replace the missing letter? The expected output is 'yu_z' and '_ux'.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the code which I tried which does not completely work but kind of give direction to where I am going:

```
rack_list = []
    for letter in letters:
        if letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
            rack_list.append(letter)
        else:
            blank_count = user_input.count("_")

    def valid_word(word, rack):
    available_letters = rack_list[:]
    missed_counter = 0

    for letter in word:
        if letter in available_letters:     
            available_letters.remove(letter)
        else:
            missed_counter += 1
    if missed_counter <= blank_count:
        for i in word:
            if i in available_letters:
                word += i
            else:
                word += "_"
        return word
```

Comment: Please adhere to the posting guidelines.  This issue is distinct from the original one; it should be a separate question.  Most of all, you've materially changed the validity of the answers posted to your original question.

Comment: Incremental "please help me" is suited for a tutor, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Prune Thank you, I've marked the question as completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of simply setting `candidate` to `False`, keep a counter of how many letters have been missed.  When that count exceeds the quantity of blanks in the rack, *then* you disqualify the word.

Also, please note that `if candidate == True` is redundant.  Use simply `if candidate`.  The value is already Boolean; there's no need to test it.

---

Code changes per OP's added attempt:

Your main problem was having the final print inside the loop; until you've checked all letters (finished the loop), you don't know whether the word is possible.

```
def valid_word(word, rack):
    available_letters = rack[:]
    blank_count = available_letters.count('_')
    # print available_letters, blank_count

    missed_counter = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter in available_letters:         
            available_letters.remove(letter)
        else:
            missed_counter += 1

    # print word, missed_counter
    if missed_counter <= blank_count:
        print(word)


# Test program
rack = ['_', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
lexicon = ['apple', 'whisky', 'yutz', 'xray', 'tux', 'xyzzy', 'zebra']

for word in lexicon: 
    valid_word(word, rack)
```

Output:

```
yutz
tux
```

Comment: Also just `return candidate`

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do what you suggested before putting it on stackoverflow. I tried range(len(word)) to make the counter. But unfortunately wasn't able to achieve the desired result. I'm quite new to Python programming and hoping if someone can change my code.

Comment: Show us where you ran into trouble with that attempt?

Comment: @Prune I've updated the question with the code I attempted. Thx

Comment: @Prune Thanks a lot, the code is working fine. Just last bit, if I want to place "_" in the word instead full word to get output like 'yu_z' and '_ux'. Basically, empty tile adds zero to scrabble score. I've updated my code in the question to reflect that. Can you pls check? Thx

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: def valid_word(word, rack_list):
 ...:     wrd = [w for w in word]
 ...:     for l in rack_list:
 ...:         try:
 ...:             wrd.remove(l)
 ...:         except:
 ...:             pass
 ...:     return len(wrd) <= ll.count('_')
 ...: 
In [2]: valid_word('tux', ['_', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
Out[2]: True

In [3]: valid_word('apple', ['_', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
Out[3]: False
In [4]: valid_word('apple', ['_', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'l', 'z', '_', 'p', '_', 'p', 'e'])
Out[4]: True
```

should work for you

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I've also updated the question with something I tried.

Comment: Let me try your solution. Thx

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a more efficient solution but this one would work:

```
letters = ['_', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

words = ['apple', 'whisky', 'yutz', 'xray', 'tux', 'zebra']

def valid_word(words, letters):
    not_valid = []
    valid = []
    wild = 0

    for letter in letters:
        if letter == '_':
            wild += 1

    for word in words:
        missing = 0
        for letter in word:
            if letter not in letters:
                missing += 1
                if missing > wild:
                    not_valid.append(word)
                    break
        if word not in not_valid:
            s = ''
            for letter in word:
                if letter in letters:
                    s += letter
                else:
                    s += '_'
            valid.append(s)

    return valid

print(valid_word(words, letters))

#output
['yu_z', '_ux']
```

So you create a not valid list, a valid list and a wild variable that counts the number of underscores in your letters list.

Then loop through your words. If the number of letters missing from the word is greater than the number of underscores counted by wild, add the word to your not valid list. Otherwise add it letter by letter your valid list, replacing any missing letters with an underscore.